# Git branch as submodule to own repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have a git repository with the following structure:

```
repo - /folder1
     - /folder2
     ...
```

This repo has 2 branches:

```
repo ┌--------- master
     |
     └--------- branch1
```

I want to add branch1 as a submodule to this repo, so that I have the following structure:

```
repo - /folder1 - /branch1 (submodule)
     - /folder2
     ...
```

I know it is possible to add a submodule that tracks a branch instead of just a specific commit, but when I attempt adding the repo as its own submodule I can't commit the result, I get the following error:

```
fatal: git cat-file :0:folder1/branch1: bad file
Unable to checkout folder1/branch1
```

Running git-fsck returns a big list of dangling blobs.

To my knowledge I haven't found anyone trying to do this. I also haven't found anything in the documentation that says that this isn't possible.

Can anyone with more knowledge of git internals explain why this isn't possible/isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Submodule can’t meet your requirement, you can use **subtree** instead.

When you add a submodule, the whole branches of the submodule repo are tracked by the main repo. So you can’t only track branch1 by submodule.

For subtree, it can add a branch to a certain path by:

`git subtree add --prefix=folder1/branch1 <repo URL> branch1`

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you mind adding an explanation on why this doesn't work? Is it because of having duplicate objects in the same repo?

Comment: Ok, if you use `git submodule add <repo URL> folder1/branch1`, and then `cd folder1/branch1`, you will find all the branches are added in submodule by `git branch -a`. And if the current branch is branch1 for the main repo, after you use `cd folder1/branch1`, you can use `git checkout master` and use `cd ..` and `cd..`. You will find your main repo’s current branch is still branch1, you only switch submodule’s repo to master branch.

Comment: But actually you don’t need to add submodule or subtree for it’s own repo. We mainly use submodule and subtree to add another repo’s stuff in current repo. So you can also directly tidy your repo’s structure as you want since all the things are only in one repo.